# Why is autoref not working for claims?

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, autoref

So I'm trying to reference a claim with autoref

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,UKenglish]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% Used for displaying a sample figure. If possible, figure files should
% be included in EPS format.
%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{theorem}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
\usepackage{comment}

\newcommand{\claimautoref}{claim}

 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{subcaption}

 \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\roman{subfigure}}

 \usepackage[ruled,vlined,algo2e]{algorithm2e}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\begin{claim}\label{add}
adfsafda
\end{claim}
\autoref{add}       

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct name of the required macro is `\claimautorefname`, not `\claimautoref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,UKenglish]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\claimautorefname}{claim} % <-- note name of macro

\begin{document}
\begin{claim}\label{add} adfsafda\end{claim}
\noindent
According to \autoref{add}, \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: I actually have a line like that in my code  line 13 \newcommand{\claimautoref}{claim}

Comment: @HaoS - I've updated my answer to mention that you weren't using the required macro name.